# How to properly use .loc on multilevel dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

Given df 'AB':

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [5, 1, 4]],
         columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = pd.DataFrame([[3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]],
         columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A'], A.columns])
B.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B'], B.columns])
AB = pd.concat([A, B], axis = 1)
```

I would like to add a column 'new' to the level 'B', based on a condition of column ['B', 'C']. I'm looking to specifically use df.loc, like this:

```
AB['B', 'new'] = 0
AB.loc[AB['B', 'C'] >= 3, 'new'] = 1
```

The problem is that this procedure creates a 'new' df instead of filling the column ['B', 'new'].

The desired output is:

```
    A           B   
    A   B   C   A   B   C   new 
1   1   5   2   3   3   3   1
2   2   4   4   2   2   2   0
3   3   3   1   4   4   4   1
4   4   2   2   5   5   5   1
5   5   1   4   6   6   6   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tuples to reference the multilevel indexes/columns:

```
AB[('B', 'new')] = 0
AB.loc[AB[('B', 'C')] >= 3, ('B', 'new')] = 1
```

Alternatively, in a single line:

```
AB[('B', 'new')] = AB[('B', 'C')].ge(3).astype(int)
```

The resulting output:

```
   A        B          
   A  B  C  A  B  C new
1  1  5  2  3  3  3   1
2  2  4  4  2  2  2   0
3  3  3  1  4  4  4   1
4  4  2  2  5  5  5   1
5  5  1  4  6  6  6   1
```

Comment: Cool, I've tried tuple before and for some reason I thought it didnt work. The bonus of your answer is learning about df.ge(). Thanks